# Should I use Webview or Android widgets for webbased Android Application?

Tags: android, json, webview

I'm planning a project which will uses JSON objects to display data on andorid mobile.

My application is some what similar to facebook application for android. It seems making detailed ui like facebook's like,comment will be time time consuming & webview seems to be better option in this case ?
need your suggestion.

I'm also planning same app to be developed on iPhone as well.

[Refrence link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-andbene2/index.html)

Comment: Applications that are just integrated browsers are stupid and never work well. Use the native interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has enough support for JSON that you can easily use the native widgets for your application. By using native widgets, the Joe Default user will have a more normal (expected) user experience, since most of the application will work just like any other Android application works.

Another thing to take into consideration that by using native widgets, it will probably be easier to add support for different UI sizes (portrait and landscape mode in various sizes can be a pain to get right in a single webview).